# Error accessing a nested repeater in parent ItemDataBound event

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, itemdatabound

**Error:**

**'Repeater' does not contain a definition for 'DataSource' and no extension method 'DataSource' accepting a first argument of type 'Repeater' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Code:

```
 protected void rptIndicator_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Repeater r2 = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rptActivity");
        r2.DataSource = dt; //Error on this line.
        r2.DataBind();
    }
```

Markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptIndicator" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptIndicator_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptActivity" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Repeater ID="rptActivityData" runat="server"></asp:Repeater>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Can you please help. Why `.DataSource` is giving me error here.

Thanks.

Comment: Is that just a copy/paste typo?  your markup lists rptActivityData but your code is looking for rptActivity

Comment: what is dt? Is that a DataTable you are populating in the ItemDataBound event?

Comment: @TheGeekYouNeed, Yes, dt is DataTable I am populating in IitemDataBound

Comment: Muhammed did you check the typo error I pointed out.  Is that a typo on Stackoverflow or in your actual code?

Comment: @Jack, there is no typo error. I have copy/paste this code in Stackoverflow. There are three Repeaters. Second one is 'rptActivity' and third one is 'rptActivityData'

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some other reference that includes a `Repeater` class in its namespace?

Perhaps try casting it to `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater`.

Comment: He is casting it by wrapping it in (Repeater)

Comment: He's casting it to a `Repeater`, but is it resolving to `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater` or `MyCustomRepeater.Repeater`? Things in the `System.Data` namespace have conflicts all the time.

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to check the ItemType or else you'll be back wondering why you're getting a runtime error.

```
switch (e.Item.ItemType) {
    case ListItemType.Item:
    case ListItemType.AlternatingItem:
         Repeater r2 = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rptActivity");
         r2.DataSource = dt; //Error on this line.
         r2.DataBind();
 }
```

I'm guessing this is a typo, but your markup lists the repeater as "**rptActivityData**" but in your code you are looking for `FindControl("rptActivity")`

Comment: thanks, I could not get it that how does .DataSource knows that I have checked ItemType or not? By the way I have tried it but same error.

Comment: -1; while you're correct, this has nothing to do with the **compile-time** error the OP is seeing.

Comment: @Adam - good point, I saw he wasn't checking for ItemType and immediately jumped to that.  I think I solved his issue, unless he just has typos in his markup.